# Set reference to Outlook 365 folder in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

My company is transferring from Outlook 16 to Outlook 365, and the Excel VBA script below now needs to refer to a mailbox in Outlook 365.

It errors on the line

```
Set oMapi = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(strMail).Folders("inbox")
```

with the error

> The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found.

Is it possible the mailbox needs to be added in a different way? Or is there a different way to do this function in Outlook 365?

I am not seeing much on a different way to do this with Outlook 365.

```
Sub Import_Email_Preferences()
    Const strMail As String = "borrowerservicesshiftbid@glhec.org"
    Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim oMapi As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strEmailAddress As String
    Dim strSenderName As String
    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim intRow As Integer

    Dim i As Long
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim ltblRow As Long
    Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Preferences").ListObjects(1)
    ltblRow = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oApp = GetObject(, "OUTLOOK.APPLICATION")
        If (oApp Is Nothing) Then Set oApp = CreateObject("OUTLOOK.APPLICATION")
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Getting Error Here
    Set oMapi = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(strMail).Folders("inbox")

    For i = oMapi.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set oMail = oMapi.Items(i)

        If TypeOf oMail Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            MsgBox = "Blue"
        End If
    Next i

    Set oApp = Nothing
    Set oMapi = Nothing
    Set oMail = Nothing
    Set oHTML = Nothing
    Set oElColl = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Add one line before that line `If oApp Is Nothing Then Msgbox "No Outlook Object was found or created"`. See if you get this message?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to reference the inbox by `GetDefaultFolder`:

```
On Error Resume Next
If oApp Is Nothing Then
    Set oApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If oApp Is Nothing Then
        Set oApp = New Outlook.Application
    End If
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set oMapi = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
```

---

If the default folder ist not accessible, be aware that folder names are language dependent, e. g. `Namespace.Folders("Posteingang")` in German.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with `Set oMapi = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(strMail).Folders("inbox")` is you are stringing references together.  This is fine if it works but you do not know what has failed if it does not.

`Set oMapi = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")` will fail if `oApp` is not an object.

`Set oMapi = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(strMail)` will fail if `oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")` is not an object.

`Set oMapi = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(strMail).Folders("inbox")` will fail if `oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(strMail)` is not an object.

I suggest trying the subroutine below to identify which step is failing.  This subroutine does everything in single steps.  It also tries different ways of achieving the same effect.  If one `Set` fails, comment it out and see if the next one works.

I have suggested some possible causes of failures but I am sure there are other possibilities.  Once you know the step that fails, come back if you need further help.

You may wish to try Asger suggestion of `GetDefaultFolder` as well.  It does not work on my system because the default Inbox in not used.  I have to name the store containing the Inbox I wish to access.

```
Sub TestGetInbox()

  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim olInbox1 As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim olInbox2 As Outlook.Folder
  Dim olInbox3 As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim olInbox4 As Outlook.Folder
  Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
  Dim olSession As Outlook.Namespace
  Dim olStore1 As Outlook.Folder
  Dim olStore2 As Outlook.Folder

  ' If execution stops her, you have a problem accessing Outlook
  Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

  ' If execution stops here, you have a problem accessing Outlook's namespace
  ' using this method. Comment out statements down to  "Set olSession = olApp.Session"
  Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

  ' If execution stops here, look at your folder pane.  Is "borrowerservicesshiftbid@glhec.org"
  ' the name of a store? Case does not seem to matter but a single letter change in the name
  ' does.
  Set olStore1 = olNs.Folders("borrowerservicesshiftbid@glhec.org")
  Debug.Print olStore1.Name

  Set olInbox1 = olStore1.Folders("Inbox")
  Debug.Print olInbox1.Name

  Set olInbox2 = olStore1.Folders("Inbox")
  Debug.Print olInbox1.Name

  ' If execution stops her, you have a problem accessing Outlook's namespace
  ' This is a different methods of accessing Outlook's namespace.  The documentation
  ' says the two method are identical but I once had the olApp.Namespace("MAPI")
  ' fail so I now always use the olApp.Session method which has never failed for me.
  Set olSession = olApp.Session

  Set olStore2 = olSession.Folders("borrowerservicesshiftbid@glhec.org")
  Debug.Print olStore2.Name

  Set olInbox3 = olStore1.Folders("Inbox")
  Debug.Print olInbox1.Name

  Set olInbox4 = olStore1.Folders("Inbox")
  Debug.Print olInbox1.Name

  Set olInbox1 = Nothing
  Set olInbox2 = Nothing
  Set olStore1 = Nothing
  Set olNs = Nothing

  Set olInbox3 = Nothing
  Set olInbox4 = Nothing
  Set olStore2 = Nothing
  Set olSession = Nothing

  Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: @Asger  Thanks.  Obvious when you think about it since, as you say, `Session` returns a namespace.